# LibreOffice download disallowed by Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, libreoffice

I'm rebuilding my PC and therefore have the latest version of Chrome. I tried downloading LibreOffice but Chrome continually stops the download with "This file can't be downloaded securely". I've Googled every permutation I can think of but there is not a general problem out there with Chrome and LibreOffice. Why does MY Chrome think that LibreOffice is unsafe?

Comment: Libre Office V7 64-bit downloaded properly here using Google Chrome.  Perhaps your Anti Virus is blocking it and Libre Office needs to be white-listed

Comment: Have you tried downloading with another browser to check if the issue is with Chrome? Are you downloading it directly from the official site?

Comment: @John The error was occurring right there in Chrome, not my Anti Virus (Defender).

Comment: I tried on two computer with success so perhaps try the following:  Uninstall Chrome, restart, install Chrome and try again.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I am downloading direct from libreoffice.org. I just tried it again (5th time) to see if it would work and it is now working OK!!

Comment: Is the result the same with another browser?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I haven't tried another browser - it is working now, so I will just chalk it up to experience. Quite troubling though...

Comment: I normally download LibreOffice using the torrent download option ...

Comment: You can also try if a Ninite installer will get it for you.  Ninite.com

Comment: The site chooses the server closest to you. Sometimes this is http. Choose a different server in a different country .. But with your language